# AGAL - position to clip space M44 op, va0,vc0

Tags: flash, stage3d, agal

M44 op, va0,vc0 - what does it mean?
this is the very first line of the vertex shader.
I see it many times however I do not understand the following:
Vc0 - empty 3d matrix - location of the object
Va0 - vertex coordinates

Why should we multiply vector on matrix?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> vc0 - empty 3d matrix
>   Why empty? In this case (and in most cases) it's MVP (model-view-projection) matrix.
>   va0 - vertex coordinates in local space (in model space). In order to make an object change it's position. orientation, scale and in order to be visible by a camera you need to apply transformations to it. That line do exactly that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was researching Starling filters in order to investigate how AGAL works. and I found that the matrix indeed is not empty, it is for vectors describing boundaries of the object (object is 2D). Va0 contains vertex position of boundary of the object (only one) - and I see that line of code is important, however, I cannot understand why we apply transformation, if va0 has boundary coordinate, matrix3D has boundaries, why this transfarmation exist is not clear.

Comment: It not exactly like this. To render a quad you need 4 vertices anyway. So va0 is not a boundary - it's a vertex. Actually you can avoid matrix multiplication in shader if you pass vertex position in normalized device coordinates (NDC). This coordinates are in range -1..+1 for x and y and 0..1 for z.

Comment: Thanks again! I think it is clear now, however I am still confused when see in rawData of my matrix (I can see when do custom filter in Staring Framework basing on the Fragment framework class) the following:
M.rawData = Vector.<Number> (@10da4da9)
0 = 0.015625
1=0
2=0
3=0
4=0
5 = -0.015625
6=0
7=0
8=0
9=0
10=1
11=0
12-
13 = 2.9334120750427246
14 = 0
15=1
fixed = false
length = 16 [0x10] I understand my words may sound stupid because I still have large gaps in this field. If you have some links to help - I will be happy about this.

Answer (score 0):

The vertex shader translates and rotates every vertex in the passed vertex buffer (va0) by the passed projection matrix in vc0 (vertex constant register 0).
The vertex buffer is the list of vertices in the model being rendered.
The projection matrix is the matrix3D of the model appended with the INVERSE of the camera's matrix3D and the PerspectiveMatrix3D.
The perspectiveMatrix3D can be set up like this:

```
projectionmatrix.perspectiveFieldOfViewRH(45.0, swfWidth / swfHeight, 1, 15000);
```

...where '45.0' is the field of view, 'swfWidth / swfHeight' is the proportion of width over height, '1' is the near clipping plane and '15000' the far clipping plane.
Multiplying the models' vertices by the projection matrix in the shader orients the model to the correct position in clip space. That's why the result of the calculation can immediately be sent to the output position register (op).

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation!
It is still complex a little bit may be I need more theory about this subject (matrix type and so forth).
I will search.
By the way, how often can we use matrixes in shaders? In most cases I have seen it once when we set OP register.

Comment: You can use matrices as often as you like, so long as it's a useful calculation. In one shader I also pass in the model's rotation Matrix (with the x,y and z postion values set to 0) which I use for reflected light calculations. It's difficult to understand at first, but yes, search around for some AGAL tutorials.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please show here this matrix, I mean there are 16 figures in the matrix? in your case it is 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1? Or I am wrong? Could you please send me AGAL tutorial?

Comment: I've actually found the Adobe docs page useful for explaining Matrix3Ds... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html And this page is probably a good place to start for AGAL...  http://iflash3d.com/shaders/my-name-is-agal-i-come-from-adobe-2/  I think, in your previous comment, you're trying to describe an 'identity matrix' - a Matrix3D with no rotation, no translation and a scale of 1. If that's what you mean, the .rawData property of an 'identity' Matrix3D would return the following Vector of Numbers: 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0